# Deja Dup: Volume doesn't implement mount

Tags: 11.10, backup, deja-dup

I am using Deja Dup for about two-three months and a week ago I started getting this error message and no backup was made:

> Backup Failed
>
> volume doesn't implement mount

Is there something wrong with my HDD?

Using ubuntu 11.10 on my asus laptop (X53SJ).

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

I think it has something to do with the location where you want to make your backup. Probably the destination became unreachable. Try changing the destination and see if you still get the error. This worked for me :P

Answer (score 0):

I got this message on ubuntu 13.10 too after having:

1. Logged-in with a user
2. Mounted an external drive
3. Switched to a second user
4. sudo umounted the external drive and mounted it within the second user

The drive resulted mounted and reachable but deja-dup was returning that error

**solution:**
rebooting and mounting directly the drive within the user I needed solved the problem